# Bash one liner - Get line group from file if matched by a string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file like;

```
A
some lines
some lines
Z
A
some lines
some lines
IMPORTANT text
some lines
Z
A
some lines
more lines
some lines
Z
A
some lines
IMPORTANT text
more lines
some lines
Z
```

I only need lines between A-Z if it has the **IMPORTANT** word. So the desired output is;

```
A
some lines
some lines
IMPORTANT text
some lines
Z
A
some lines
IMPORTANT text
more lines
some lines
Z
```

The line count between A-Z is variable. I tried too many commands like:

```
grep 'IMPORTANT' -A 3 -B 3 x.log | sed -n '/^A$/,/^Z$/p'
grep 'IMPORTANT' -A 3 -B 3 x.log | grep -E '^Z$' -B 5 | grep -E '^A$' -A 5
```

Some printed not needed lines from another group, other printed lines without starting or ending points... And all failed.

Is there any way to do this with a one liner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using gnu-awk you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\nZ\n"} /^A/ && /IMPORTANT/' file
A
some lines
some lines
IMPORTANT text
some lines
Z
A
some lines
IMPORTANT text
more lines
some lines
Z
```

- `BEGIN{RS=ORS="\nZ\n"}` sets input ad output record separators as `Z` with newlines on either side.
- `/^A/ && /IMPORTANT/` ensures that each record starts with `A` and has `IMPORTANT` in it.
- each matching is printed as that is default action in `awk`

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This command took only 5 secs to run in real log file (~4.5M, ~87k lines).

Comment: Thanks so much @EdMorton, that is definitely more concise (edited)

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/^A$/{:a;N;/\nZ$/!ba;/IMPORTANT/p}' x.log
```

Explained:

```
/^A$/ {            # If line matches ^A$...
    :a             # Label to branch to
    N              # Append next line to pattern space
    /\nZ$/!ba      # Branch to :a if pattern space doesn't end with \nZ
    /IMPORTANT/p   # Print if pattern space contains IMPORTANT
}
```

This basically appends lines until we have a complete block in the pattern space, then prints it if it matches `IMPORTANT` and just discards it otherwise.

The `-n` option prevents output when we reach the end of a cycle.

Some seds don't support oneliners with command grouping (`{}` with `;`) or inline comments. For some seds, having `p;` instead of `p` works, and for others, this (basically the above minus comments) should work (and is POSIX compliant):

```
sed -n '/^A$/{
    :a
    N
    /\nZ$/!ba
    /IMPORTANT/p
}' x.log
```

Comment: This apparently requires GNU `sed`; it does not work as-is with the `sed` that ships with Mac OS X.

Comment: Any idea where the GNUism is?

Comment: Not really :) The error I got was `sed: 1: "/^A$/{:a;N;/\nZ$/!ba;/I ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: Try `p;`, and if that doesn't work, the multiline version should. (And let me know so I can amend the answer :) ) (Multiline without comments, that is.)

Comment: Looks like you need to use newlines, not semicolons, to separate the functions inside `{...}`. (Just `p;` gives the same error.)

Comment: Apparently older seds require the `{` to end the line and the `}` to be on a line on its own.

Comment: @chepner You should upgrade your sed to a version compatible to POSIX or use GNU sed. ;)

Comment: Don't tell me; tell Apple :) (As far as I can tell, though, the POSIX spec doesn't require semicolons to be recognized as command separators inside `{`).

Comment: @chepner No, no!! I was wrong! :) Seems that allowing `{}` in one line is a GNUism or at leat not POSIX conform. I've just run GNU sed trough `sed --posix` and it worked, however [the spec says there shall be newlines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: This worked great on test file. But in real log file (~4.5M, ~87k lines) it took 3.5 mins before i killed.

Comment: @hek2mgl All bases covered now, I think!